# Java File IO + relative paths + NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

Quite simply:

```
File account = new File("./data/account");
account.createNewFile();
```

Gives me:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:900)
  ...
```

Why Does file.createNewFile() give me a `IOException` with the message `No such file or directory`? I'm telling it to create the file.

Running this code outside of NetBeans seems to work with no problem, can NetBeans not handle relative file links?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does the directory `./data` exist?

Comment: . may refer to a different directory when running in Netbeans than the command line.

Comment: @Jeffrey . I feel a bit like an idiot now, no ./data does not exist. It did before I migrated the project into netbeans, that could explain it... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `./data` does not exist, that call will fail.

```
File f = new File("./data/account");
if(!f.getParentFile().exists()) { // if the directories don't exist
    if(!f.getParentFile().mkdirs()) { // if making the directories fails
        // directories weren't created, throw exception or something
    }
}
f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Appreciate it. Will this have any undesirable affects if the current path does already exist though?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is running the java program from the `dist` folder.  You would need to create the `data` folder in there.  However, I believe in some cases, Netbeans will clean out the entire folder and therefore delete it.  I would use an absolute path.

Comment: Let's say to avoid this issue I want to create `account` if it doesn't already exist, and also create `./data` too.

Comment: That would be the safest route.